# Find two smallest Integer that when added are smaller that x but bigger than x when multiplied together

Tags: sum

I have searched for this everywhere but I couldn't find it anywhere, sorry if this questions has already been posted. Please refer me to it if this already exists somewhere else, thank you :)

Ok so here are the two rules to follow, for a number 'N' return the two Integers (x and y) that:

1. When added together is smaller than 'N'.
2. When multiplied together is bigger than 'N'

Example: for N = 15, X = 4 and Y = 4, when added together make 8, but make 16 when multiplied together. 
**Note:** X = 4 and Y = 5 would be a valid answer as well, but for this specific question, the valid solution needs to add up to the smallest value possible. (4 + 5 = 9 > 8)

Hopefully this makes sense, all I am really looking for is the logic to approach this from, not necessarily a full on solution written in code but I would still take it if anyone feels like it :)

My biggest issue here is how to know that you have the smallest two ints (optimal solution), especially when we get to bigger and bigger number?

```
var N = 15;
var x, y = 0;
while(keepLooping) {
    if((x+y < N) && (x*y > N)) {
        //values found that respects the clauses
        keepLooping = false;
        break;
    } else {
        if((x < y) || (x==y)) {
            x++
        } else {
            y++
        }
    }
}
```

My logic here is to start with both numbers at 0 and to slowly increment each of them by 1 but also test if the clauses are respected between each increment. To me this insures that I get the smallest values because I am starting from 0.

This is how see it;

```
Does is work with:
x=0, y=0... False
x=1, y=0... False
x=1, y=1... False
x=2, y=1... False
...
```

Comment: This seems more of a math question, than a programming one. x+y < N; x*y>N.  Two equations, if my math is right, x*x-N*x+N<0.   Then, you are only dealing with x and N.

Comment: In fact, if x * y > N, y > N/x ; x + y < N, y < N -x.  This dimly reminds me of the intersection of two functions, but in this case, you are looking at regions, not the intersection.

Comment: More thoughts on this; this is similar to the 'maximum area encompassed by a minimal rectangular fence' problem in calc, x and y are continuous there.  For an integer solution, it would seem values + or - 1 from sqrt(N) would be good candidates.

Comment: You’re correct, this is more of a math problem than a programming one, the reason I phrased it as a programming problem is because I was asked to program this logic for an exam and I had no idea how to approach this. I see that you are approchaient this with a math perspective, which I totally get why, but do you have any idea how this could be approached code-wise? No particular language. I know how to find two numbers that respect the two clauses, but I don’t know how to be sure that they are the smallest ones possible.

Comment: Uh, I don't think we are supposed to solve your exam problems here.  We can look at a program you create, and help if there are glitches.   Try something in your favorite language...

Comment: Sure, I get that, but not to worry the exam is finished and I probably failed that portion. I wanted to get back to that problem and try to understand how I should've approached it. I will try to remember what kind of logic I used and will post the code I wrote later. thanks